# Sprite will not draw to screen when globally declared, will when declared within function

Tags: c

Writing a program in which a sprite is drawn to the screen and moves one pixel upwards every 50ms. When i declare the sprite and bitmap within the function it draws but does not move, when I declare it globally it does not appear at all. My code looks correct but won't work.

```
Sprite hero_sprite; //declared globally outside of main
Sprite * hero_sprite_pointer = &hero_sprite;
byte hero_bitmap [] = {
    BYTE( 10100000 ),
    BYTE( 11100000 ),
    BYTE( 10100000 )
};

void setup_hero(Sprite hero_sprite, byte * hero_bitmap) {

    init_sprite(hero_sprite_pointer, 46, 23, 3, 3, hero_bitmap);
    draw_sprite(hero_sprite_pointer);
    hero_sprite.dx = 1;
    hero_sprite.dy = 0;

while (1) {
    update_hero();
    draw_sprite( hero_sprite_pointer ); 
    _delay_ms( 50 );
    refresh();
    }

}


void update_hero(Sprite * hero_sprite) {
    hero_sprite->x += hero_sprite->dx;
    hero_sprite->y += hero_sprite->dy;
}
```

init sprite initializes the original position of whatever sprite is being drawn.
draw sprite actually displays it. i've tested to see if the while loop is running, which it is, but wont draw the sprite.

EDIT: Calls to the functions are this

```
void init_sprite(
Sprite * sprite,
byte x,
byte y,
byte width,
byte height,
byte * bitmap
) {
sprite->x = x;
sprite->y = y;
sprite->width = width;
sprite->height = height;
sprite->bitmap = bitmap;
}

void draw_sprite( Sprite * sprite ) {
if ( !sprite->is_visible ) return;

// Index into the bitmap. This is updated as we traverse the 
// pixels of the image.
int idx = 0;

for ( int row = 0; row < sprite->height; row++ ) {
    float screen_y = sprite->y + row;

    if ( screen_y < 0 ) continue;

    if ( screen_y >= LCD_Y ) break;

    int col = 0;
    int bitmask = 1 << 7;

    while ( col < sprite->width ) {
        byte pixel = sprite->bitmap[idx] & bitmask;
        float screen_x = sprite->x + col;

        if ( (screen_x >= 0) && ( screen_x < LCD_X ) && pixel ) {
            // Set pixel only if the bit is set. 0 is transparent.
            set_pixel( screen_x, screen_y, 1 );
        }

        col++;

        if ( col % 8 == 0 ) {
            idx++;
            bitmask = 1 << 7;
        }
        else {
            bitmask >>= 1;
        }
    }

    if ( sprite->width % 8 != 0 ) {
        idx++;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you include the calls to these two functions?

Comment: For starters, your call inside your `while` loop: `update_hero()` is supposed to take a parameter.